# having difficulty proving logical equivalence of this.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Here is the question I'm stuck on

$\lnot q \land (p \lor q) \equiv p \land \lnot q$

I can not even figure out which law to apply first.

Comment: [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Rule_of_replacement).

Comment: im having a lot of trouble still, as from what i see the distributive law involves 3 propositions like p, q and r.

Comment: You have three : $p, q$ and $\lnot q$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
 \lnot q \land (p \lor q) &\equiv (\lnot q \land p) \lor (\lnot q \land q) &\text{distributivity}\\
 &\equiv (\lnot q \land p) \lor \bot &\text{contradiction}\\
 &\equiv \lnot q \land p &\text{neutral element for }\lor\\
 &\equiv p \land \lnot q &\text{commutativity}
\end{align}
where $\bot$ stands for absurdity or contradiction, i.e. a formula that is always false.

Comment: sorry to sound daft, but what allows you to just remove the contradiction?

Comment: @JesseBounds - For every formula $A$, one has $A \lor \bot \equiv A$. You can prove it through a truth table, keeping in mind that $\bot$ is a formula that is always false. This means that $\bot$ is the neutral element for $\lor$.